# Im having difficulty in validating through loops

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have here in my database:

```
___________________________
|id|Date      |stime|etime|
|1 |2014-02-02|01:00|02:00|
|2 |2014-02-02|03:00|04:00|
```

I have inserted this manually

then i have to find a specific time where to put my other time:

> 1. cannot insert same stime and etime
> 2. cannot insert between stime and etime
> 3. the end time must not be the same as stime vice versa

I have my code here:

```
      echo  $stime = ($_POST['stime']);
       echo  '----';
       echo  $etime = ($_POST['etime']);
       echo  '<br>';
     $date = "2014-02-02";
  if($stime < $etime){
      $sql_all = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE date='$date' AND (stime='$stime' AND etime='$etime')";
      $query_all = mysql_query($sql_all);  
      $get_rows=  mysql_num_rows($query_all);
      if($get_rows == 1){
        echo 'validate: time already taken choose another time please';
      }else{
        echo 'VALIDATE : insert if the time is not yet taken';
             $new_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time");
            while($get_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_all)){
              echo "<br>";
              echo   $g_all_stime = $get_all['stime'];       
              echo "----";
              echo   $g_all_etime = $get_all['etime'];
              echo "<br>";       
                if($stime == $g_all_stime && $etime == $g_all_etime){
                    echo 'There is already a time like yours';  
                }
                elseif($stime <= $g_all_stime && $etime >= $g_all_etime){
                    echo 'cannot insert the same Start and End time';  
                }
                elseif($stime >= $g_all_stime && $etime <= $g_all_etime){
                    echo 'the time must not be between the earlier reserve time';
                }
                elseif($etime >= $g_all_stime && $stime <= $g_all_etime){
                    echo 'the end time must not be the same as the start time and the end time must not 
                    be the same with the end time';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'ELSE no other choice insert here';
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO time(`date`,`stime`,`etime`) VALUES('$date','$stime','$etime')";            
                    //mysql_query($sql_insert);
                }
            }
      }

 }else{
     echo 'do not insert';
 }
```

then the result is like this

```
01:00----02:00 //this is the input
VALIDATE : insert if the time is not yet taken // validates the input
01:00----02:00 //this part is checking if it has same data type in the database
There is already a time like yours //validates ^
03:00----04:00 //this is the 2nd column in the database
// this always end up in inserting my input
ELSE no other choice insert here
INSERT INTO time(`date`,`stime`,`etime`) VALUES('2014-02-04','01:00','02:00')
```

**PLEASE POINT WHERE I'm WRONG HERE**

If there is already a problem like this will you post the link

Comment: Should 2:00-3:00 really be blocked? It is by your problem description.

Comment: @DavidHarkness the main problem here is every time i enter any different/same kind of time at the end it always insert because of the else function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use a DATETIME column type, it will be easier to validate.

You can do this with a very simple query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE 
($start < `end`)
AND
($end > `start`);
```

If the query returns any row, you will throw an error.

Like this.

```
<?php
    if ($result > 0) {
        echo 'Error';
    } else {
        echo 'Success';
    }
```

The $start and $end variables are your input dates. :)

Comment: im kinda confused about the busy and available datatype? what's the purpose of that?

Comment: It's just for exemplifying. If the query returns more than one row, you will negate the validation. You can select count(*), for example.

Comment: If you make those `>=` and `<=` I think it'll work, assuming continuous time blocks are truly not allowed.